# Python reading a PE file and changing resource section

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open a Windows PE file and alter some strings in the resource section.

```
f = open('c:\test\file.exe', 'rb')
file = f.read()
if b'A'*10 in file:
    s = file.replace(b'A'*10, newstring)
```

In the resource section I have a string that is just:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
```

And I want to replace that with something else. When I read the file I get:

```
\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A\x00A
```

I have tried opening with UTF-16 and decoding as UTF-16 but then I run into a error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 1604-1605: illegal encoding
```

Everyone I seen who had the same issue fixed by decoding to UTF-16. I am not sure why this doesn't work for me.

Comment: What codes are those, in that position 1604-1605? Windows does not use UTF-16, it has a [multibyte wide encoding of its own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/multibyte-and-wide-characters?view=vs-2017). Presumably – just like with a UTF-8 file that contains nothing higher than a tilde – those others for whom it worked just got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

If resource inside binary file is encoded to utf-16, you shouldn't change encoding.

try this

```
f = open('c:\\test\\file.exe', 'rb')
file = f.read()

unicode_str = u'AAAAAAAAAA'
encoded_str = unicode_str.encode('UTF-16')

if encoded_str in file:
    s = file.replace(encoded_str, new_utf_string.encode('UTF-16'))
```

inside binary file everything is encoded, keep in mind